# Find the Laurent series of the function and give the residue

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have $f(z)={z^2\over {z^2-1}}$. I want to find the Laurent series of $f$ and the residue at the point $z_0=1$.

Can I say that $f$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=1?$ Or is that only used when the denominator looks like $(z-z_0)^m$.

I let $H(z)=z^2/z+1$, then take the 1st and 2nd derivative. I get $H(1)=1/2, H'(1)=3/4$ and $H''(1)=1/4$. Would the residue of the function at $z=1$ just be $1/2$?

And I do not know how to get the Laurent series.

Comment: The pole has order $1$.

Comment: right, because you factor out. What about the residue?

Comment: Many ways, find limit as $z$ approaches $1$ of $z-1$ times our function. We get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I actually used the residue theory to get 1/2, can I look at the laurent series to conclude the residue in this case?

Comment: Sure, from the series you can read off the residue.

Comment: my problem is I don't know how to compute the Laurent series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z)={1\over{z-1}}{z^2\over {z+1}}={1\over{z-1}}{(z-1+1)^2\over {z-1+2}}={1\over 2}{1\over{z-1}}{((z-1)+1)^2\over{1+(z-1)/2}}=\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not a Laurent series, is it?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^n=1/(1-w)$.